# how to close bootstrap modal if used class="modal show"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using class="modal show" in bootstrap modal to show modal by default on form load.
But I am unable to close this modal with class="modal show" class, if I used class="modal fade" instead of class="modal show" , its working fine.
Working code are given below.

```
  <div class="modal show modal-xs" id="paymentStatus" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-body">
         <span> <?php echo $_SESSION['status_message'];?></span>
    </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you rewrite your question with better English please? I can't understand it.

Comment: Could you please create a [mcve] and clearly specify what is the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hardcoded css class .show to show your modal when initialized. Instead, use `data-show="true"`

In your example :

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-show="true"></div>
```

More info in bootstrap doc :
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

Comment: tried <div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-show="true"></div> this code but its not display on load.

Comment: did you include bootstrap javascript file in you html file ? can you edit your question and provide your html head and javascript file included ?

Comment: Yes I added bootstrap javascript

Comment: So you'll have to do it the old fashion way : `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#modal').modal('show');
    });
</script>` . Also, you need to provide more information about your code if you want us to help.